# How to get my dropdown image button to remain active when clicked

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to do something that's really simple but for some reason I can't get this figured out. If you look at the "ALL" button and when you hover over you'll see "active", "pending", and "sold". When the user clicks on one of those options, let's say "pending", I want it to remain at "pending" so he knows what he's looking at. Right now when you click on any of those options it automatically reverts back to the "All". The link is below:

http://fireflyliving.com/new/

```
  var nav = $("#catpicker");  
  //add indicators and hovers to submenu parents  
  nav.find("li").each(function() {  
  if ($(this).find("ul").length > 0) {    
      //show subnav on hover  
      $(this).mouseenter(function() {  
          $(this).find("ul").stop(true, true).slideDown();  
      });  
      //hide submenus on exit  
      $(this).mouseleave(function() {  
          $(this).find("ul").stop(true, true).slideUp();  
      });  
  }  
  });
```

Comment: Where is the click event code that you have written.. You would need to replace the image src when the element is clicked

Comment: Look at this and tell me if this works for you http://jsbin.com/omuvaq/1#

Comment: Hey Praveen, that works and is exactly what I was looking for! However The only thing I noticed though is that the "ALL" button is showing twice. And when you click on one of the other buttons it duplicates itself! Is there a way to stop that from happening so that it only shows one of each button?

Answer (score 0):

You need yo attach click events and handlers for every available state, otherwise is impossible to achieve what you are asking for.

Something like this:

```
$('#pending-state').click(function(){
    $('not:(.pending)').hide();
});
```

pending-state id is the pending clickable image and .pending are all the elements with the state pending.

You have here a demo of what I'm talking about click events:

http://jsfiddle.net/BpD8c/1/

Comment: Hey, sorry I'm not to familiar with jQuery. Would I add this code to what I already have? Thank you!

Comment: I don't know. You need to trigger different handlers for different events. You already have the handlers for mouseenter and mouseover events. The next step is attach handlers for click event on the selected filter.